# How can I hide the safari toolbar on ios on a page where the body doesn't scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, safari

I'm making a site that incorporates a parallax banner using a pure CSS parallax style page banner using a method by Keith Clark ([Pure CSS Parallax Websites](https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/)). This is an image of how it is set up on my site: [image: parallax banner visualisation] However, in order for this method to work the body remains fixed while the wrapper scrolls. Generally, this works and I haven't found any accessibility issues with it on desktop browsers but I have found that this method can cause some issues on safari on ios. The main one is that because only the wrapper scrolls and not the body, the safari toolbar does not automatically hide and instead is fixed all the time. It also means that safari doesn't display the scrollbar of the page correctly and another minor side-effect of this is that the user cannot click the status bar to go back to the top of the page.

Does anyone know of a workaround that could help prevent some of these issues, even just the hiding of the safari toolbar? I'm open to re-engineering the parallax effect if there are better ways of achieving the effect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.